# A font to typeset proofreader's marks in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I always overlook mistakes when I proofread documents on screen.  When I proofread a printed paper I can find much more mistakes and mark them with the defined proofreader's marks – for German language in the book *"Der Duden"*, for English language look for example in [the Chicago manual of style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_proof.html).

Is there any font available to typeset proofreader's marks in LaTeX ? I want to print a short flyer to show students the meaning of proofreader's marks.

Comment: Since few may have access to *Der Duden*, is [this list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/mw/table/proofrea.htm) something comparable? If not, is it possible to post something similar for German (as an image, say)?

Comment: There is a PDF with the proofread marks, but I am probably not allowed to copy them here(?) http://www.pirrot-verlag.de/downloads/korrekturzeichen.pdf

Comment: While these are not the traditional proofreader's marks, they however are in the spirit and could easily be used in a LaTeX file. http://www.d.umn.edu/cla/faculty/troufs/comp3160/proofreaders_marks.pdf

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: I’m not sure, that the Pirrot-Verlag is the original publisher, cf. https://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=korrekturzeichen&as_filetype=pdf – there’s an almost identical version on a site of the Humboldt university. “Almost” means, there is ewrite.de given as the source.

Comment: Do you have that flyer available for download? I'd need such a thing, too

Comment: @ThomasWeller Please follow the link given in the comment of user Speravir ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be no Type1 font for use with pdftex. But with LuaTeX or XeTeX you can try out the TrueType font “Proofreader”, that provides proofmarks used in German Language. It can be downloaded in a ZIP file from http://www.maxfonts.com/fonts/p/proofreader.font (the link to the original vendor is dead) and used for free (the license is CC BY-ND 3.0). As you are a German, you can read the included PDF file. *(For all: The mapping is shown in this file. It should be also recognizable, if you don’t understand German, search for “Tastenbelegung”.)* In my humble opinion the “deleatur” sign is ugly, the “kursiv“ line is angular instead of wavy.

I think it would be the best to create a new fontfamily (means: use `fontspec`) and an own speaking command for every proofmark, because the mapping to the letters looks like it was done at random.

A very different and perhaps much better approach may be to draw all proofmarks with TikZ or something similar and assign them to own (speaking) commands.

**Update:** Though they are not TeX related, I want to add some links: [PDF Editing – Making the Most of the Stamps Tool](http://www.louiseharnbyproofreader.com/4/post/2012/01/pdf-editing-making-the-most-of-the-stamps-tool.html) and [Free Stamp Collections for PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/stamp_collections). At least the marks dedicated for PDF-XChange Viewer are embedded in PDF files and could therefore used in other ways.

Comment: I didn’t think of a package either. BTW: To be honest take a look on the search results of the link I gave in my comment to Patrick above and use one of these PDF files for your purpose.