# How do I make a separation mark in Turkish proofreading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations, proofreading

I am making a proofreading mark.
MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
Electricheater % to be separately written

Electri$\underline{c}$/$\overline{h}$eater % Like _/‾
\end{document}
```

Is there anyone who can make it better?

**Added:**

[image]

Comment: This could be misinterpreted: that shape is sometimes used to indicate that one should start a new paragraph. Better to imitate standard proofreader’s marks. Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65740/ ?

Comment: @Thérèse, Yes, I have. But I am trying to do it for Turkish. I edited the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this solution two macros are defined. The first is `\slsh`, which defines the diagonal line between the words. You can adjust the height by changing the `2.2ex` and adjust the amount of slant by changing the `1.2ex`, but keep the `ex` units.

The second macro is called `\addspace`, which calculates the dimensions of `\slsh`, draws the `\slsh` between the words you want, and adds lines below and above using `\llap` and `\rlap` to overlap with existing text. I set a `1em` overlap, but you can set that to any length.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for \resizebox
\usepackage{calc} % needed to subtract from \hght

\newlength{\wdth}
\newlength{\hght}
\newlength{\dpth}

\newcommand{\slsh}{\resizebox{1.2ex}{2.2ex}{\normalfont /}}
\newcommand{\addspace}{\settowidth{\wdth}{\slsh}\settoheight{\hght}{\slsh}\settodepth{\dpth}{\slsh}%
    \llap{\rule[-\dpth]{1em}{.09ex}}\hspace{-.13\wdth}\slsh%
    \hspace{-.15\wdth}\rlap{\rule[\hght-.09ex]{1em}{.09ex}}}

\begin{document}
Electric\addspace heater

\emph{Electric\addspace heater}

\textbf{Electric\addspace heater}

{\large Electric\addspace heater}

{\Large Electric\addspace heater}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've realized now. Two words must be between the separating words because they are contiguous.

Comment: Please check the image of question.

Answer (score 4):

This does what you want in a more convinient way:

The macro `\sepafter` has two arguments. The first will be underlined and the second overlined. Between them a `/` is set.

By making use of the fact, that without `{}` TeX takes one token as argument (i.e. one letter here), it is possible to write `\sepafter ch` to get the `c` underlined and the `h` overlined with a `/` between them.

This is not perfect, as can be seen with italic or slanted fonts. Therefore, `\sepafter` has an optional argument to adjust the necessary correction. But even with this it's not perfect.

**Edit:** added color. `\sepafter` now uses `corrcolor` for the correction mark. It is defined in the preamble.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{corrcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\newbox\beforebox
\newbox\afterbox
\newbox\slashbox
\def\sepcorrection{-0.1em} % default correction
\newcommand*{\sepafter}[3][\sepcorrection]{%
    \setbox\beforebox\hbox{#2}% for measuring the width
    \setbox\afterbox\hbox{#3}%
    \setbox\slashbox\hbox{/}% for measuring height and depth
    \mbox{}% to make it work at the begining of an indented paragraph
    \rlap{#2}% print argument with 0 width, overlaping to the right
    {\color{corrcolor}%
    \rule[-\dp\slashbox]{\wd\beforebox}{0.1ex}% the underline
    \hskip#1/\hskip#1}% apply some correction, so under-/overline meet slash
    \rlap{#3}%
    {\color{corrcolor}%
    \rule[\ht\slashbox]{\wd\afterbox}{0.1ex}}% the overline
}

\begin{document}
Electricheater % to be separately written

Electri\sepafter cheater \quad just one letter on each side

Electri\sepafter cHeater \quad just one letter on each side, right side is upper case

Elect\sepafter{ric}{hea}ter \quad mark a few letters on each side

\sepafter{Electric}{heater} \quad mark whole words

Elect\sepafter{ric}heater \quad mark a few letters on left side

Electri\sepafter c{hea}ter \quad mark a few letters on right side

\vspace{1ex}
\textbf{\Huge Elect\sepafter{ric}{hea}ter} \quad other size

\vspace{1ex}
\textit{Elect\sepafter[0.04em]{ric}{hea}ter} \quad italic needs different correction, but still not perfect

\textsl{Elect\sepafter[0.04em]{ric}{hea}ter} \quad same for slanted

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution provided me with new information. But I will choose the answer of Sandy G.