# How do I make a letter or word delete mark in proofreading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, proofreading

I'm sorry I did not write MWE but I do not know how to do it in any way. I think it will be easy with `pgf`.

[image]

I just want to do the red parts. I am leading this problem to friends who can do this.

My try

```
\newcommand*\delete[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(foo.base)] \draw node [append after command={(foo)node [above right=-.1]  {$\sim$}},draw,ellipse,thick,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,] (foo){$\displaystyle#1$};}
```

Comment: are you aware of [pdfcomment](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment)?

Comment: @marmot, yes I know. Not a solution to the my problem.

Comment: Using an image editor (e.g. Gimp) will probably be easier.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65740/a-font-to-typeset-proofreaders-marks-in-latex

Comment: What's Turkish got to do with these marks? You can basically ask how to draw those squiggly lines right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. You can adjust the delete mark however you see fit by adjusting the coordinates, thickness or looseness in the `\draw` command.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\wordlen}

\newcommand{\delete}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\wordlen}{#1}\hspace{.5\wordlen}\tikz[anchor=base,baseline, overlay]{%
    \node[inner sep=1,circle,very thick,draw=red](word){#1};%
    \draw[very thick,red,overlay](word)to[out=20,in=-90](.5,.4)to[out=90,in=90](.4,.4)to[out=-90,in=-150](.8,.4);}%
    \hspace{.5\wordlen}}

\begin{document}
Here is a sentence with no meaningful content.
Here is another sentence with no meaningful content. 
Here is one more sentence with no \delete{no} meaningful content.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With percusse's help (see comments), the left mark is easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {\includegraphics{hKBg1}};
\fill[white] ([shift={(1.5,0.5)}]A.south west) rectangle ([shift={(4,1.6)}]A.south west);

\draw[red,ultra thick]
([shift={(1.5,0.5)}]A.south west)
..controls +(90pt,65pt) and +(-95pt,-25pt) .. ++(60pt,25pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to *draw* the proofreader's marks on text, not cover them up in a picture... Consider his example syntax: `\delete{it}` should draw a red circle around *it* and then draw the delete proofreader's mark.

Comment: Actually, maybe I misunderstand too, since he has already asked and received an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402937/how-to-word-delete-mark-in-turkish-proofreading?rq=1

Comment: @DavidPurton, just like you wrote.

Comment: @Özgür Are you looking for something like this ? `\tikz{ \draw[red, thick] (70pt,20pt) ..controls (250pt,150pt) and (0pt,20pt) .. (190pt,70pt);}`

Comment: @percusse I think I should delete my answer because I compltetly misunderstood the question. Will your comment be affected by this deletion? Could Özgür still read it?

Comment: No Ignasi, please don't :-) can you get my comment into your answer? We don't need extra clutter. I just made something up by an online graphics tool so the numbers might be all moot.