# How to word delete mark in Turkish proofreading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape, proofreading

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgflibraryshapes}
\begin{document}

\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]
\node(a) [red,draw,ellipse,thick,fill=white,inner sep=2pt](x){\color{black}{delete}};
\tikz \draw[baseline=(a.east),red,thick] (0,0)-- (.2,.2)--(.5,.2);

\end{document}
```

but what I try to do

[image].

Can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use two separate `tikzpicture`s (`\tikz` is a shortform for `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`), place both `\node` and `\draw` in the same, and then draw the line starting at `x.east`, using relative coordinates (indicated by `++`).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]
{
\node [draw=red,text=black,ellipse,thick,fill=white,inner sep=2pt] (x) {delete};
% ++ means that the coordinate is relative to the previous one
\draw[red,thick] (x.east) -- ++(.2,.2) -- ++(.3,0);
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect working.