# Character for missing paragraph

Tags: symbols, characters

I am looking for a character to indicate a missing paragraph. It is used in German schools when correcting essays.

The character is used like this and looks like the red one here *[(source)](https://www.typolexikon.de/korrekturzeichen/)*:

[image: Usage of the missing paragraph sign]

I have tried:

- [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but the best results are just `\rfloor` and `\lceil`, where I would need a combination of both
- googling for *latex missing paragraph*, which yields a lot of results regarding `\paragraph`, which is not what I need.

I am not looking for ¶ `\textparagraph`, of course.

Comment: Please see this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65740/16550! Duplicate?

Comment: Well it is not really a symbol that you typeset, you write them. There seem to be a font here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65740/a-font-to-typeset-proofreaders-marks-in-latex/66408.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: yes, that's true. However, when writing about those symbols / describing them, I don't want to add them manually into the PDF. (I don't even know how I would do that, except printing and scanning)

Comment: I would probably just do this: to give them a "handwritten look" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `tikz` and the library `calc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\missingParagraph}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node[left] (mleft) at (0,0) {};
        \node[right] (mright) at (0.025,0) {};
        \draw[red, thick] ($(mleft.south west)+(-0.05,0)$) -| ($(mright.north west)+(-0.05,0.25)$) -- ($(mright.north west)+(+0.2,0.25)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

    bis zum bitteren Zeilenende.\missingParagraph Hier 

    soll ein Absatz eingefügt werden.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not so optimized, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an answer here: As you will probably not publish anything containing these symbols, you can just produce one by hand, like the following.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{color,mathtools}
\newcommand{\linebreaksign}{\ensuremath{\mathclap{\color{red}\rfloor\hspace{-1.37mm}\lceil}}}

\begin{document}
    Here should be a \linebreaksign{} linebreak
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]